# Android Messaging app - Client - Server Communication

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to write a private messaging app similar to Whats App. Smartphones with Android OS shall be the clients and communicating with one server. Now my question is how could that work out?

I guess the best way would be via a Restful webservice as port forwarding is absolutely no option. So what is the better way? - Client asking every few seconds if there are new messages or is there a way how the server can notify the client when there is a new message, and the client just sends a sign of life every few minutes? How does whats app do that?

Would UDP holepunching or reverse TCP any good in this case?

Comment: You can use GCM to notify your client for a new message. GCM can wakeup your client application. Please check https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need real time communication. Basic approach would be using `WebSockets`. I would recommend you to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) that already makes use of `webSockets` and is very scalable. Going for [node.js](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) is a great life saver in this matter. There are many `socket.io java clients`to use in your android app such as:

https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java

There are also things like [Pusher](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client) that uses push messages and is ready for use.